# Double variable Char variable

Tags: c++, char

I need a little help. The question is very simple but sorry for my limited knowledge. I want to convert a 1D double array to a char matrix like this..for example..the first element of the double matrix is

```
double version[6];
char version_ch[6][6];
version[0]=1.1587
```

I want to convert version[0] into version_ch[0][5] and so on. Each version variable is 6 digits.Can anybody please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `double` confusing ?? you wants 2-D matrix? as you are assigning double value `1.1513` and *`want to convert version[0][0] into version_ch[0][6].`* not clear

Comment: Could you try to be clearer, I cant understand what you are trying to achieve.. Also, `version_ch[0][6]` is out of bounds

Comment: You do know that the string `"1.1513"` is *seven* characters? You must have the string terminator character as well. And is there a reason you don't use `std::string` and `std::vector` or `std::array`?

Comment: You should really consider stating the underlying problem instead of the problem with your approach of solving it. There might after all a better solution...

Comment: I agree with Grizzly, why do you need to do this? What are you going to use `version_ch` for? You might want to read [about the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually want the char array that you ask for then you could generate it like this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

// ...

    static const size_t VERSION_N_ELEM = 6;
    static const size_t VERSION_STR_LEN = 6;

    double version[VERSION_N_ELEM];
    char version_ch[VERSION_N_ELEM][VERSION_STR_LEN];

    char buf[32];
    for (int i = 0; i < VERSION_N_ELEM; ++i) {
        sprintf(buf, "%.4f", version[i]);
        strncpy(version_ch[i], buf, VERSION_STR_LEN);
    }
```

This is more of a c approach than c++, but then again, using arrays like you are is more of a c approach than c++ anyway.  The use of sprintf here is not entirely safe.  If you have sprintf_s or snprintf in your compiler library you should consider using that. or use stingstreams.

Since you say very little about the intended purpose, you should be aware that the strings in the char 'matrix' may not be null terminated as there is not enough space for that.

Comment: @pete..thanks a lot..this is what i was planning to do...to get the access to the resulting char array..thanks

Comment: Can you tell me how i can do vicaversa?..means to convert `version_ch[0][6]` to `double version[0]`?

Comment: @SaadSaadi Use the [`strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) function. But then the string have to be a proper string with string terminator.

Comment: @SaadSaadi yes as Joachim Pileborg suggests use strtod.  Since the strings in this matrix are potentially not null terminated, you'll need a 7byte array to strncpy the string into and set the last byte to 0 to ensure it is null ternimated.  then use strtod on that.  Or, you could make your original 'char matrix' a [6][7] array and make all the rows null-terminated to avoid the copy.  I don't know if that is possible based upon your requirements for this array?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
const size_t num_versions = 6;

std::array<double, num_versions> version;
version[0] = 1.1587;
// ...

std::array<std::string, num_versions> version_str;
std::transform(std::begin(version), std::end(version), std::begin(version_str),
    [](const double& value) { return std::to_string(value); });
```

Read about [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: the question is not tagged as being c++11

Answer (score 0):

what you are asking for is plain bad design in c++. You can obtain your result with, say, this code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
        double version[4] = {1.2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8};
        char version_ch[4][3];

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                stringstream ss; 
                ss << version[i];
                string tmp_str = ss.str();
                for(unsigned int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                        version_ch[i][j] = tmp_str.c_str()[j];
                }   
        }   
}
```

but, seriously, you should revise your design!